# ability to create a new session for every BrowserWindow object?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, session, electron

In my JS class constructer I have a variable.

```
this.cookieBrowser = new BrowserWindow({ show: true, webPreferences: { webSecurity: false } });
```

I later then call that variable in a function to create a new window... this works just fine... However, for each task (child process) that I am running, the cookies / session data are the SAME - but I need each browser to have a different session.

I was wondering if there was any way to complete this task as each object is currently returning the exact same set of cookies.

I have tried clearing the session every time I call the function using:

```
    that.cookieBrowser.webContents.session.clearStorageData([], await function (data) {

    })
```

This seems to just clear the cookies temporarily - all cookies are still the same in the long run.

Answer (score 4):

You should specify a different (persisted or not persisted) partition for each browserwindow.

```
    this.cookieBrowser = new BrowserWindow({
        show: true,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            partition: 'unique_random_path' // OR  'persist:unique_random_path' to save session on disk 
        } 
    });

    this.cookieBrowser2 = new BrowserWindow({
        show: true,
        webPreferences: {
            webSecurity: false,
            partition: 'unique_random_path2' // OR  'persist:unique_random_path2' to save session on disk 
        } 
    });
```

You can achieve the same result by passing a [session object](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/session.md#class-session) to `webPreferences`.

See [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#new-browserwindowoptions) all browserWindow options and the difference between `session` and `partition` property.

Comment: quick question about the path: would an unique ID be fine?
example: partition: `${this.taskID}` (random hex value)

Comment: the partition property wants a string. If you create multiple browserwindow with the same partition, they will share the session. If partition string is different, session will not be shared. So, the unique random hex value is a suitable value if you need different session for each browserwindow.